# is there a generic way to know if a file is a supported image type?

Tags: android, image

is there a way to know whether a file is a supported image type in a generic way?  of course, i could look at the filename extension and compare it against a known set of strings, but is there an "android" way of doing this more generically?

really, i want to know whether or not I can decode and display the image.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is better way (still using BitmapFactory though). You can use the same factory but NOT read the bitmap itself (which is much faster of course). There is a decodeFile version which has Options parameter and you can specify that it should only read bitmap size (and type of course) rather than bitmap itself:

```
String filePath;// assign the file to the path
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath, options);
if (img == null) {
  // invalid image file
}
else {
  // valid image file
}
```

Comment: hm...  interesting.  that is better, but it still has to crack open the file...  better though...

Comment: No way to check it without reading the file :)  (unless you rely on extensions)... I think this is fastest way..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (and most reliable) way to do it is to try to open and [decode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.html#decodeFile%28java.lang.String%29) it as a `Bitmap` - something like:

```
String filePath;// assign the file to the path
Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
if (img == null) {
  // invalid image file
}
else {
  // valid image file
}
```

It's not pretty but it works.

Comment: okay, but is there a way to do it without cracking open the file?  like if i could even get a list of supported file extensions from the OS that would be okay...  I just don't want to hardcode "JPG", "BMP, "GIF", "PNG"

Comment: I don't know of anything like that.